# Tring to save two records to database within 1 defintition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My question is:

How can I run the second part AFTER the first part runs and finishes the save. So the second part can duplicate most of it with the altered column data.

```
Is there a after_new  or  Then clause I can use in ruby?
```

I have an script on my site that adds parameters to a database table so that the site will notify if there is a posted match.

The below is the original def script. ( I want to make it add 2 separate records to the database if the search_type = "load". Only changing load parameter to "hotload"

```
  def self.convert_saved_search_to_notification(id)
    search = Search.find(id)
    options = search.attributes
    options[:notification_type] = options.delete("search_type")
    options[:radius] = search.origin_radius unless search.origin_radius.blank?
    Notification.new(options)
  end
```

I have tried to do this but it only saves the second part.

```
  def self.convert_saved_search_to_notification(id)
    search = Search.find(id)
    options = search.attributes
    options[:notification_type] = options.delete("search_type")
    options[:radius] = search.origin_radius unless search.origin_radius.blank?
    Notification.new(options)

 // SECOUND PART

    if options[:notification_type] == "load"
      search = Search.find(id)
      options = search.attributes
      options[:notification_type] = "hotload"
      options[:radius] = search.origin_radius unless search.origin_radius.blank?
      Notification.new(options)
    end
  end
```

I would make a second definition but I am new to ruby on rails and I don't know how to redirect to another def. after save

Even tried this and still only save second part

```
  def self.convert_saved_search_to_notification(id)
    search = Search.find(id)
    options = search.attributes
    options[:notification_type] = options.delete("search_type")
    options[:radius] = search.origin_radius unless search.origin_radius.blank?
    Notification.new(options)

 // SECOUND PART

    if options[:notification_type] == "load"
      search1 = Search.find(id)
      options1 = search1.attributes
      options1[:notification_type] = "hotload"
      options1[:radius] = search1.origin_radius unless search1.origin_radius.blank?
      Notification.new(options1)
    end
  end
```

Would like to get this (removed a few columns for simplicity)

```
  ID         User    radius  notification_type
251941  |  10181  |  175  |  hotload  |  
251942  |  10181  |  175  |  load     |
```

Comment: `Notification.new` will make a new object in memory but NOT save it to the database.  `.create` will make it in memory then save it to the DB.  This might be your problem but i'm a bit unsure about what you're trying to do. fyi what you "defs" are called "methods" in ruby.  All methods are called on objects, which, if you're "inside" an object, defaults to "self", ie the object you're inside.

Comment: ok i changed the .new to .create on both instances and it enteed twice but both Notification types were "load"

Comment: my bad i got it i missed changing one of the "options" to "options1" that took care of what i needed done. if you answer the question i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know how to answer without seeing the full context of the call to the method, but I notice you're doing `Notifications.new` which is building a new notification but not saving it to the database.  This suggests that the 'save' happens after the method results are returned.

You haven't shown the code that calls this class method...but I would guess the call is something like

```
result = Object.convert_saved_search_to_notification(id) 
result.save
```

So the problem could be that you're returning one object (the last evaluated statement) when you want (in some cases) to return two objects.

You could try...

```
  def self.convert_saved_search_to_notification(id)
    second_notification = nil

    search = Search.find(id)
    options = search.attributes
    options[:notification_type] = options.delete("search_type")
    options[:radius] = search.origin_radius unless search.origin_radius.blank?
    first_notification = Notification.new(options)

 // SECOUND PART

    if options[:notification_type] == "load"
      search = Search.find(id)
      options = search.attributes
      options[:notification_type] = "hotload"
      options[:radius] = search.origin_radius unless search.origin_radius.blank?
      second_notification = Notification.new(options)
    end
    return first_notification, second_notification
  end
```

Then when you call the class method...

```
result1, result2 = Object.convert_saved_search_to_notification(id)
result1.save
result2.save if result2
```